# Filtered list with parent items - selected by cursor arrows. AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my form i have input with dropdown, in dropdown I show json data like:

```
{
    "title": "Parent #1",
    "child" : [
        {"title":  "Child ##1"},
        {"title":  "Child ##2"},
        {"title":  "Child ##3"},
        {"title":  "Child ##4"}
    ]
}
```

I bind it to such html:

```
<div class='dropDownContainer'>
    <div class='filteredItemContainer'>
        <ul>
            <h5>Parent title</h5>
            <ul>
                <li>Child items</li>
                <li>Child items</li>
            </ul>
        </ul
    </div>
</div>
```

User can select any item - parent or child.
I need to add possibility select item by cursor.
How i can implement such functionality? I know how to do with simple ul list, but i don't know how to do it with such structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean displaying the JSON data obtained as the list and bing able to set one of the items as 'selected', you could implement it with the following changes to your code.

```
<!--html-->
<div class='dropDownContainer'>
    <div class='filteredItemContainer'>
        <ul>
            <h5>Parent title</h5>
            <ul kb-item="item" ng-repeat="item in mydata">
                <li>{{item.title}}</li>
            </ul>
        </ul
    </div>
</div>



//js, in your app controller, install module and add as a app dependancy
```

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['keyboard']);

```
myService.getData().then(function(data){
   $scope.mydata = data;
});
```

Comment: I mean select items using arrows on keyborad.

Comment: this module - https://github.com/bfanger/angular-keyboard should help with that; check the demo with the list of items and keyboard navigation http://angular-keyboard.herokuapp.com/example-orientation.html - see the updated answer